# Shutting down Akka system when in Play2 development mode

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka, akka-cluster

I'm developing my app with Akka and Play2.

When I run the play2 app with `~run` the first time and I make a GET my custom Actor system is created in the Controller and it starts a cluster on 2558 port.

If a change anything in my code and make another GET play recompiles and start over as it suppose to but the 2558 port is taken and I've got error: `Failed to bind to /127.0.0.1:2558`.

I don't know how to handle my own actors systems shutdown to work well with play2.
I've tried to do it in the `GlobalSettings` object in `onStop` method but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka.system` to get an actor system.  You can customise this actor system however you want in `application.conf`.  Play automatically starts it up and shuts it down for you.

If for some reason you really don't want to use this (but really, I can't think of any reason why you would ever not use it), then you need to wait for the actor system to shutdown in the `GlobalSettings.onStop` method, using `ActorSystem.awaitTermination`.  Calling `shutdown` is non blocking, so when Play starts it back up, it's likely that the `ActorSystem` won't have fully shut down and released the port yet.

Also, don't create the actor system in a controller.  Either create it in `Global`, or implement the `play.api.Plugin` interface and create one there (the latter is preferred for anything that has a lifecycle).

Comment: Is there any reason why I shouldn't be creating them there? I was thinking of creating multiple Controllers every one of them with it's own Actor system to have controll over the executioncontex.

Anyway thanks for the answer. It helped!

Comment: An `ActorSystem` is a heavyweight object, there's little reason to have more than one.  If you want multiple execution contexts (I'm assuming these are for futures), you can create your own in `application.conf` and look it up using the global actor system. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.4/scala/dispatchers.html

Comment: Partially yes, it is for futures but not only. I have a concern that with a huge load of request some actors may be put into starvation eventually. Especially if most of the Controller methods will use the `ask` pattern. 

Anyway I didn't know I can create actors on a different dispatcher. This seems to answer my question. 
Thank you!